# Guideliness to write junit test cases for if,loop and exception

Tags: junit

I'm new to Junit. I want to write test cases for if condition,loops.

Do we have any guidelines or procedure to write test cases for if,loop conditions?
Can anyone explain with an example?

```
IF Age < 18 THEN WHILE Age <> 18

  DO ResultResult = Result +1 AgeAge = Age +1 END
  DO Print “You can start driving in {Result} years” 

ELSE 

 Print “You can start driving now!” 

ENDIF
```

Comment: WC to SO add some relevant source code in the post , so it could help us a lot

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response.May i know wat is WC?

Comment: For Example This is my program:                                    IF Age < 18 THEN   
WHILE Age <> 18 DO  
ResultResult = Result +1  
AgeAge = Age +1  
ENDDO  
Print “You can start driving in {Result} years”   
ELSE  
Print “You can start driving now!”   
ENDIF                                                                How to wrtie test cases for if condition in junit

Comment: From my understanding of writing in junit for java ,we were used to create a  source code into different blocks is the code conventional,and used to pass the values as args to the function  from the test cases so the values will steps into the block statements ,and passes the test cases ,

Comment: Can u give some examples.So that i can understand more.Do you have any idea how to write test case for the above example.Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure , its very simple to write first of all have clear understanding in junit ,in this [link](:www.vogella.com/articles/JUnit/article.html) tutorial is available , it would help you a lot

Comment: I learn't Junit from that site and worked out with an example.The example in the site has just a method and some logic's it doesn't have any condition.All I want to know is how to write test cases for the conditions inside a method.

Comment: For example you are having the variable as age by assuming as functionName(int age),  for testing you should should pass the integer from the test case as functionName(18) it will steps into the statements and will show you the status of the test case.

Answer (score 2):

You want one test case for each major scenario that your code is supposed to be able to handle.  With an "if" statement, there are generally two cases, although you might include a third case which is the "boundary" of the two.  With a loop, you might want to include a case where the loop is run multiple times, and also a case where the loop is not run at all.

In  your particular example, I would write three test cases - one where the age is less than 18, one where the age is exactly 18, and one where the age is over 18.  In JUnit, each test case is a separate method inside a test class.  Each test method should run the code that you're testing, in the particular scenario, then assert that the result was correct.

Lastly, you need to consider what to call each test method.  I strongly recommend using a sentence that indicates which scenario you're testing, and what you expect to happen.  Some people like to begin their test method names with the word "test"; but my experience is that this tends to draw attention away from what CONDITION you're trying to test, and draws attention toward which particular method or function it is that you're testing, and you tend to get lower quality tests as a result.  For your example, I would call the test methods something like this.

```
public void canStartDrivingIfAgeOver18()
public void canStartDrivingIfAgeEquals18()
public void numberOfYearsRemainingIsShownIfAgeUnder18()
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of writing in junit for java ,we were used to create a source code into different blocks is the code conventional,and used to pass the values as args to the function from the test cases so the values will steps into the block statements ,and passes the test cases .

For example you are having the variable as age by assuming as functionName(int age), for testing you should pass the integer from the test case as functionName(18) it will steps into the statements and will show you the status of the test case.Create test case for a testing class write test case for the functions

```
UseClass classObj=new UseClass();// it should be your class

    @Test
      public void testValidateAge() {
          classObj.validateAge("20");
          assertEquals(200,"");
   }
```

Correct me if 'm wrong :)